# Add hot point in android application based on Arcgis SDK

Tags: android, arcgis-android

I am working on an application based on Arcgis android SDK.

Now I wonder if I can add the hot point like google map and etc.

For example, not matter you use google map in pc or your phone, when you touch the text or symbol of the poi, the detail information of the poi will be displayed by inforwindow(pc) or something else.

I wonder if we can make it in android?

Answer (score 1):

With ArcGIS Android API you can easily show a callout on a point added to a map. You can further [customize](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/customizing-the-callout.htm) the callout as well.  To replicate the simplicity you are suggesting try using the [Application Framework](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/application-framework.htm).

Comment: The framework I referenced has been re-branded to toolkit.  You can also look at popups in the API.